# meta tag, inserido em fragmento de html dinamicamente no body, funciona?

Tags: php, facebook, html-meta-tag

Eu tenho um laço de repetição que insere `<div>`'s. Essas `<div>`'s são conteudos com texto vindo do banco e com a opção de compartilhar no `facebook`. 
No momento em que eu gero essas div's eu insiro umas tags `<meta>` aquelas do  facebook, porém elas ficam no conteúdo do `<body>`. Até o momento elas não funcionam, mas elas deveriam funcionar? Ou essas tags são vão funcionar se eu incluir elas na tag `<head>` ?

No meu sistema eu consigo compartilhar corretamente em alguns lugares, mas eu insiro o conteudo das tags pelo controller ai sim, vão para o `<head>` e funcionam, mas nesse momento esses textos ficaram em `.collapse`'s e terão vários outros na mesma página.

```
foreach ($ordemdia as $key => $ordem) {
 return "<meta property='og:image' content='/upload/itens/images/thumbs/{$ordem['tbvereadores']['img']}'>
.<div class='col-md-12'>...#conteudo...</div>";
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essas metas precisam ficar no `<head>` e elas são únicas por página porque eles guardam os parâmetros `og` da página em questão, e não de uma div.

Comment: exato, foi bem isso que eu pensei. Obrigado pela resposta.